# Will the upcoming experiment PICO measure kSZ temperature anisotropy?

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

I know for sure PICO will be measuring polarization anisotropies with high fidelity. In addition, the PICO science paper shows that it will make full-sky Compton-y maps but the plots are mostly limited to l=1000. Will PICO be able to measure kSZ temperature anisotropy at l=3000?

Comment: Please explain all the acronyms and jargon.

Comment: [PICO - the probe of inflation and cosmic origins](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01368)